# Printing HTML blocks

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a page with a few tables that I want to be printable. I want the following behaviour:

1) Add a page break if the next table fits in a single page, but won't fit in the current page 
(because of other stuff already printed on this page)

2) Print the "table header" again in case it's needed to break a table (I guess it's the default behaviour)

Any ideas specially on the first issue? Maybe some CSS can help?

I'll give on example. I have a page with 4 tables. All of them with 10 lines, except the third one, with 50 lines.
The first and second goes on the first page. Since the third one won't fit in the same page, but will fit in a page alone, it's printed on a page alone... and then the forth table is printed on the third page (in case it doesn't fit together in the second page).

But, if the third page had 300 lines and would be broke anyway, it could have started to be print in the first page.

Answer (score 1):

So much of that kind of stuff differs browser to browser. I spent what seemed like countless hours trying to get that kind of functionality using only css, but most of the page layout stuff is in the unsupported end of css3.

Some things like `page-break-*` are supported by some browsers and it would be worth a try to implement them.

This article (http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=26) does a good job of going over most of what you are looking for.